# Window.print() will not work on my webapp. Tried 3 different methods

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to open the print dialogue box on my web app, but cannot get it to work. I've tried jQuery first which was:

```
$('#print').click(function(e){
    console.log('test');
    window.print();
  });
```

This logged 'test' but did nothing else. I then tried the vanilla route:

```
  document.getElementById('print').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log('test');
    window.print();
  });
```

With the same result. Lastly, I tried:

```
 <button class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="window.print();" id="print">
    <img class="btn__image" src="../images/print.svg">
    Print
 </button>
```

Again, with the same result. I'm using php, which should not matter.

This is what is completely throwing me off: It works on w3schools' example.

I am using bootstrap as well as chartjs, fullcalendar, and moment.js.

Comment: What happens if you press `ctrl+p`? Does the dialog appear? `window.print()` is the correct call

Comment: this is a standard JavaScript method, it may be getting overriden. Try on a page that is not using the JS frameworks you have.

Comment: Try this: `console.log(window.print)` Should say `print() { [native code] }`

Comment: Ctrl+p (Cmd+p) does work for opening the print dialogue. When I console log out window.print() it is returning undefined. I ctrl/cmd clicked on the function which took me to the function declaration (VS Code). It is saying void, but looking at the file path, the reference seems to be in the default VS Code files.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound silly, but try changing the `id` of the `button` to something other than `print`, like `printpage` for instance. I have seen similar issues with `button`s that have an `id` of `submit` and `form.submit()` does not respond.